# How to disable an edit button for the records older than 3 days

Tags: javascript, php, date

I have a table where all the daily records are displayed.[image: Table which shows all the daily records]

I want to disable the edit button if the records are 3 days older. How can i obtain this. i have current date and 3 day ago date using php date function. can it be done using php only or javascript can be used??

```
<?php $current_date = date('Y-m-d');// current date
$days_ago = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 days', strtotime($current_date)));
//3 days older date
```

I am displaying the records like this:

```
foreach($records as $rec){
 $count = $count+1;
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rec['client_name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rec['address']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rec['task']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rec['fiber_length']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rec['phone_number']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rec['package']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rec['result']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rec['date']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rec['team_name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rec['remarks']; ?></td>
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>staff_activity/edit_ftth_report/<?php echo $rec['id']?>">Edit</a></td>
 <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="chk('<?php echo base_url(); ?>staff_activity/delete_ftth_report/<?php echo $rec['id']  ?>')">Delete</a></td>

  </tr>

 <?php

 }?>
```

Comment: you can do this one with simple php 
Try using something like this

    if(strtotime('2016-06-23 14:13:20') < strtotime('-3 days')) {
          // this is true
      }

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strtotime($current_date) > time()-(60*60*24*3))
```